# pouchdb not working on ios safari

Tags: android, ios, cordova, safari, pouchdb

I am trying to write a cordova application that uses pouchdb as offline DB (without sqlite). my app works from all browsers and from android but not ios. am not sure why is that and what to do to fi it! here is my code to initialise the db:

```
app.onDeviceReady = function() {
try {
    console.log("starting db");
    window.offline_db = new PouchDB('offline_db');
    if (window.offline_db.adapter) {
        console.log("db started!");
    }
    offline_db.get("op_settings", function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(doc);
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}};
```

this does not return the doc, even though when I save the doc it says it was saved successfully, it only gives a promise but no result.

Also on safari Mac I can see the db content in debugger, but on safari ios I dont have this tab under resources

[image: Safari Mac screenshot]

Comment: It looks like the promise is not being returned/the callback is never fired but no error either!

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you have put your callback function on the place of options to be passed(optional):
[PouchDB get](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#fetch_document)

Please try

```
offline_db.get("op_settings", null, function(err, doc)
```

it should work.

Comment: I took the code from the link you shared (it does not pass null) anyway I just tried it and it did not work.

Comment: also as I mentioned it is working on all platforms except for ios

Comment: Then I can only suggest debugger; :)